# ASP.NET MVC usercontrol create and edit mode setting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) usercontrol to represent a form for both a "create" mode and an "edit" mode.

The form involves a file upload so looks something like this:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

How can I make it post to the Create action in create mode and Edit action in edit mode?

I'm rendering it in the View like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("NewsForm"); %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Don't specify the action name in your call to `Html.BeginForm`. By default the same action name is used for `POST` as for `GET` (and similarly for controller). So if you just do:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

...then you get what you want.

A general rule of thumb for ASP.NET MVC is, "If your code is not doing what you want, try removing some of it."

Comment: I like you general rule of thumb!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to take all the fields and put them into a partial view and have the main view (Create/Edit) do the different begin forms.